# Why does the CPU usage go to 100% after pressing % in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm very new at Prolog, but am already well aware that the code shown here is not tail-recursive, and therefore not optimal. I'm working my way up to tail-recursion, but have a question in the meantime.

I was trying to write a factorial function, and have arrived at the the following...

```
f(0, F) :- F is 1.
f(N, F) :- N > 0,
           N1 is N - 1,
           f(N1, F1),
           F is N * F1.
```

When I run this with a value of 50000, it gives me the answer in a couple of seconds. The CPU hardly rises.

If I then press the `;` key the CPU goes to 100% for about 20 seconds.

Now I don't understand this. With code that can bind to multiple values, each time you press `;`, it goes off and works out the next binding that matches. However, in this case, what is it doing? There's nothing else to bind, so why doesn't it just stop immediately?

In case it makes any difference, I'm using SWI-Prolog on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: On mine, SWI 9.0.3 on Windows, it says `false` almost immediately. After the base case `f(0, 1).` succeeds and you ask it to retry, it has to try the second rule for input of 0 - `f(0, F)`, and then I think unwind the stack all the way back to the top after that fails. Which I guess is optimised more in newer SWI versions, maybe? https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=zcompare/3 has some discussion about making a deterministic factorial which won't prompt after finding a solution because it can tell there are no more.

Comment: Does not reproduce for me either. What is the output of `?- version.` on your SWI-Prolog? I am using 'threaded, 64 bits, version 9.1.7'

Comment: What was your *exact* query? That 50000! is a large, a very large number, should be obvious.

Comment: Say `listing(f)` to see if what you are running is actually what you display here.

Comment: @false I ran the code with 50_000, it takes 1.5 seconds, the result has 213237 digits.

Comment: @TA_intern: (Fast machine...) But upon `;` you get rapid failure.

Comment: @false Yes, fails immediately.

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments, I just installed SWI Prolog on my Windows 11 lap top, and the code runs as expected, first calculation takes 1-2 seconds, and then failing is almost immediate. Not sure what went wrong on Ubuntu, but seems to work fine on WIndows.